# json object is too complex for ADF dataflow to parse/roll

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory

I have a json which looks like below:

[image]

I need to collect the seller ID and seller Name for now. I was trying to achieve in adf data flow but it was un able to roll it by sellers for some reason in the flatten transformation . Seems like this not a valid array.

what I tried:

1. I tried some other ways like copying it into blob and tweaked some
   settings like file pattern as 'array of objects' and feed it as a source to dataflow which
   didn't work.
2. Try to use some aggregate transformation but not sure how to apply it. I am new to dataflow.

Can it be done easily in pyspark if its not possible in dataflow at all is also I am open to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I have taken the following sample data in order to get the `sellerID and sellerName`.

```
{
   "timestamp":1686036525840,
   "tokensLeft":1,
   "refillIn":1,
   "refillRate":1,
   "tokenFlowReduction":0.0,
   "tokensConsumed":2,
   "processingTimeInMs":0,
   "sellers":{
      "ABC":{
         "trackedSince":1,
         "domainId":1,
         "sellerId":"XX",
         "sellerName":"LS",
         "csv":[
            [
               6062020
            ],
            [
               6062020
            ]
         ],
         "lastUpdate":6536604,
         "isScammer":false,
         "hasFBA":true,
         "totalStorefrontAsins":[
            1,
            44
         ],
         "sellerCategoryStatistics":[
            {
               "catId":1,
               "productCount":2,
               "avg30SalesRank":3,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":5
            },
            {
               "catId":3,
               "productCount":11,
               "avg30SalesRank":72203,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":3
            }
         ],
         "sellerBrandStatistics":[
            {
               "brand":"1",
               "productCount":3,
               "avg30SalesRank":18820,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":0
            },
            {
               "brand":"l3",
               "productCount":3,
               "avg30SalesRank":32525,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":1
            },
            {
               "brand":"1",
               "productCount":3,
               "avg30SalesRank":40102,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":1
            },
            {
               "brand":"1",
               "productCount":1,
               "avg30SalesRank":5315,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":0
            }
         ],
         "shipsFromChina":false,
         "address":[
            "1"
         ],
         "recentFeedback":[
            {
               "rating":10,
               "date":6531840,
               "feedback":"Never .  Black ",
               "isStriked":true
            },
            {
               "rating":50,
               "date":6523200,
               "feedback":"I received.",
               "isStriked":false
            },
            {
               "rating":50,
               "date":6521760,
               "feedback":"Fast ship a",
               "isStriked":false
            },
            {
               "rating":50,
               "date":6518880,
               "feedback":"It  to .",
               "isStriked":false
            },
            {
               "rating":20,
               "date":6517440,
               "feedback":"I r .",
               "isStriked":true
            }
         ],
         "lastRatingUpdate":6536604,
         "neutralRating":[
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
         ],
         "negativeRating":[
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2
         ],
         "positiveRating":[
            100,
            100,
            98,
            98
         ],
         "ratingCount":[
            7,
            23,
            59,
            59
         ],
         "currentRating":1,
         "currentRatingCount":1,
         "ratingsLast30Days":6
      },
      "XYZ":{
         "trackedSince":2795761,
         "domainId":1,
         "sellerId":"CVB",
         "sellerName":"ABC",
         "csv":[
            [
               271
            ],
            [
               6,
               46101
            ]
         ],
         "lastUpdate":6536586,
         "isScammer":false,
         "hasFBA":true,
         "totalStorefrontAsins":[
            1,
            1
         ],
         "sellerCategoryStatistics":[
            {
               "catId":1,
               "productCount":131,
               "avg30SalesRank":11,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":1
            },
            {
               "catId":3760911,
               "productCount":106,
               "avg30SalesRank":101900,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":8
            },
            {
               "catId":1055398,
               "productCount":93,
               "avg30SalesRank":107441,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":41
            },
            {
               "catId":3760901,
               "productCount":60,
               "avg30SalesRank":11,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":3
            },
            {
               "catId":11,
               "productCount":11,
               "avg30SalesRank":11,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":5
            },
            {
               "catId":11,
               "productCount":28,
               "avg30SalesRank":489,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":23
            },
            {
               "catId":1,
               "productCount":1,
               "avg30SalesRank":1,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":0
            },
            {
               "catId":1,
               "productCount":12,
               "avg30SalesRank":1,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":0
            },
            {
               "catId":1,
               "productCount":8,
               "avg30SalesRank":1,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":4
            },
            {
               "catId":1,
               "productCount":6,
               "avg30SalesRank":1,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":3
            }
         ],
         "sellerBrandStatistics":[
            {
               "brand":"1e",
               "productCount":35,
               "avg30SalesRank":1,
               "productCountWithAmazonOffer":0
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

- Now, using the select transformation with rule-based mapping, I have selected the properties of `sellers`.

[image]

- I have used derived column transformation to add a new column called `columns` with the value as `columnNames('select1')` which would give me an array column with value as `["ABC","XYZ"]` (the keys which we need).

[image]

- I have using sink cache and writing to the activity output. The following is the complete Dataflow JSON:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          timestamp as integer,",
                "          tokensLeft as integer,",
                "          refillIn as integer,",
                "          refillRate as integer,",
                "          tokenFlowReduction as double,",
                "          tokensConsumed as integer,",
                "          processingTimeInMs as integer,",
                "          sellers as (ABC as (trackedSince as integer, domainId as integer, sellerId as string, sellerName as string, csv as integer[][], lastUpdate as integer, isScammer as boolean, hasFBA as boolean, totalStorefrontAsins as integer[], sellerCategoryStatistics as (catId as integer, productCount as integer, avg30SalesRank as integer, productCountWithAmazonOffer as integer)[], sellerBrandStatistics as (brand as string, productCount as integer, avg30SalesRank as integer, productCountWithAmazonOffer as integer)[], shipsFromChina as boolean, address as string[], recentFeedback as (rating as integer, date as integer, feedback as string, isStriked as boolean)[], lastRatingUpdate as integer, neutralRating as integer[], negativeRating as integer[], positiveRating as integer[], ratingCount as integer[], currentRating as integer, currentRatingCount as integer, ratingsLast30Days as integer), XYZ as (trackedSince as integer, domainId as integer, sellerId as string, sellerName as string, csv as integer[][], lastUpdate as integer, isScammer as boolean, hasFBA as boolean, totalStorefrontAsins as integer[], sellerCategoryStatistics as (catId as integer, productCount as integer, avg30SalesRank as integer, productCountWithAmazonOffer as integer)[], sellerBrandStatistics as (brand as string, productCount as integer, avg30SalesRank as integer, productCountWithAmazonOffer as integer)[]))",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> source1",
                "source1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          each(sellers,match(true()))",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 derive(columns = columnNames('select1')) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

- Now, iterate over the columns array as shown in the above image using the items value as `@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0].columns`
- Inside the for each, first I have a set variable activity to build each object containing `sellerId and sellerName` with following dynamic content:

```
{
"sellerId":"@{activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0][item()].sellerId}",
"sellerName":"@{activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0][item()].sellerName}"
}
```

[image]

- Now, I have used append variable activity after this to append this object to an array variable using the dynamic content `@json(variables('tp'))`.

[image]

- I have used another set variable activity for demonstration purposes to show the value of this array that was just built.

[image]

- Now you can write this variable's value to a file as JSON. Refer to the solution provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76424475/get-all-output-of-dataflow/76428951#76428951). The following is the Pipeline Json:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Data flow1",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "dataflow1",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference"
                    },
                    "compute": {
                        "coreCount": 8,
                        "computeType": "General"
                    },
                    "traceLevel": "None",
                    "cacheSinks": {
                        "firstRowOnly": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Data flow1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0].columns",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "req",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(variables('tp'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable1",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "tp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "{\n    \"sellerId\":\"@{activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0][item()].sellerId}\",\n    \"sellerName\":\"@{activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0][item()].sellerName}\"\n}",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable2",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "test",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@variables('req')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "tp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "req": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "test": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply @Saideep. But will this work if there are multiple sellers? since I can see in hierarchy level we have selected ABC which is hard coded. How can we make it dynamic so that it can traverse deep for multiple sellers?

Comment: Yes, you are right, for multiple objects, the approach would change. This solution works for the given data only.

Comment: Can you suggest me an approach for multiple objects to work?

Comment: Can you edit the question to give a sample example of multiple objects as text instead of image?

Comment: I have added the edit as requested

Comment: Hey @Andy, I have updated the answer. Check if it helps

Comment: @Saideep..sory for being late since I was waiting for weekend to try this. This is freaking awesome!! saved me a lot of work since I was almost setting up adb to meet this. Thanks a lot  for the effort you have put in here!!  one last qs..do i need to write a store proc to write it into db or there any easy way to write this seller name and seller id column into database.

Comment: Hey @Andy, if you are looking to write into a database, then you can write a stored procedure and find a way to send the array of objects as rows to your table. If its azure sql database, you can use somthing like OPENJSON

Comment: @Saideep...Once comment which I found during my testing...in the projection the two seller id s are becoming hardcoded and every time I pass new seller ids the two seller ids (which are in the projection in source) are coming hardcoded.

Comment: ideally the projection should be dynamic with the filename which I am parsing. I am also passing filename as a parameter  to the Data flow dataset in the source but it seems the projection is storing the schema with the the sample sellers we imported at first time. From next time it giving me the seller name and seller id of the new items but the 1st two iteration are failing since it always  looking for those hardcoded selller which are in the projection.

Comment: Hey @Andy, the projection has to be dynamic automatically. Try creating a new dataflow and try again